# JavaScript's forEach method taking a function as a parameter that takes an argument that seems it has no role

Tags: javascript, foreach

I've encountered with this piece of code in a book I'm reading, and I couldn't understand what the b argument that is defined in the function inside the forEach method does.

Here's the source code:

```
var tab = [2, 3, 5];
tab.map(x => x + 3)
   .filter(x => x > 5)
   .forEach(function(a,b){console.log(a-3);});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've dug a bit deeper and found out that the function inside the `forEach()` method can take up to 3 arguments, so the function can be written like this: `forEach(function(a, b, c) { // Instructions });` with `a` being the element of the current iteration, `b` being the index of that element and `c` being the array itself.

Example:

```
const samples = ['sample_1', 'sample_2', 'sample_3'];
samples.forEach(function(a, b, c){
    console.log(a); // shows the element
    console.log(b); // shows the index of the element
    console.log(c); // shows the whole array
    console.log('Onto the next sample.')
});
```

In this example, on the first iteration, `a` will be 'sample_1' `b` will be 0 and `c` will be the whole array.
Second iteration, `a` is 'sample_2', `b` will be 1 and `c` will be the whole array.
And so on with all the remaining iterations. Note that the function inside the `forEach()` method takes only 3 arguments, not more.

Answer (score 0):

b is optional, it is the index of the element